# How to analize the complexity of this Algorithm? In term of T(n)

Tags: algorithm, math

> Analyze the complexity of the following algorithms. Said T(n) the running time of the algorithm, determine a function f (n) such that T(n) = O(f(n)). Also, let's say if it also applies T(n) = Θ(f(n)). The answers must be motivated.

I never do this kind of exercise.
Could someone explain what I have to analyze and how can I do it?

```
j=1,k=0;
while j<=n do
    for l=1 to n-j do
        k=k+j;
    end for
    j=j*4;
end while
```

Thank you.

Comment: Typically with these questions you need to (algebraically) calculate the number of times that the *inner loop* runs. Start by 1) determining how many times it runs as a function of `n` and `j`, and 2) summing these over all values of `j` encountered, as a function of `n`.

Comment: So the inner loop runs (n-j)*(the number of while loops) times , the while runs n/4 times. I'm not sure this is my first exercise. I don't understand why O(n*log(n)).

Comment: "the while runs n/4 times" – are you sure? Note that the factor of 4 is *multiplied*, not added.

Comment: Thank you really, now I understand what are you saying,  j , every loop, increment by its quadruple so its like base 4 logarithm function, right?

Comment: Well, almost – `j` increases exponentially, and the outer loops runs `~ log4(n)` times.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the number of times each instruction is executed depending on `n` (the variable input). Let's call that the cost of each instruction. Typically, some parts of the algorithm are run a significantly greater number of times more often than other parts. Also typically, this "significantly greater number" is such that it asymptotically dominates all others, meaning that as `n` grows larger, the cost of all other instructions become negligible. Once you understand that, you simply have to figure out the cost of the significant instruction, or at least what it is proportional to.

In your example, two instructions are potentially costly; let `k=k+j;` cost `x`, and `j=j*4;` cost `y`.

```
j=1,k=0; // Negligible
while j<=n do
    for l=1 to n-j do
        k=k+j; // Run x times
    end for
    j=j*4; // Run y times
end while
```

Being tied to only one loop, `y` is easier to determine. The outer loop runs for `j` from `1` to `n`, with `j` growing exponentially: its value follows the sequence `[1, 4, 16, 64, ...]` (the `i`-th term is `4^i`, starting at `0`). That simply means that `y` is proportional to the logarithm of `n` (of any base, because all logarithms are proportional). So `y = O(log n)`.

Now for `x`: we know it is a multiple of `y` since it is tied to an inner loop. For each time the outer loop runs, this inner loop runs for `l` from `1` to `n-j`, with `l` growing linearly (it's a for loop). That means it simply runs `n-j-1` times, or `n-1 - 4^i` with `i` being the index of the current outer loop, starting at `0`.

Since `y = O(log n)`, `x` is proportional to the sum of `n - 1 - 4^i`, for `i` from `0` to `log n`, or

```
(n-1 - 4^0) + (n-1 - 4^1) + (n-1 - 4^2) + ... =
((log n)-1) * (n-1) - (1-4^(log n))/(1-4) =
O(log n * n) + O(n) =
O(n log n)
```

And here is your answer: `x = O(n log n)`, which dominates all other costs, so the total complexity of the algorithm is `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Following on from the comments, the value of `j` can be written as a **power of 4**. Therefore the code can be re-written in the following way:

```
i=0,k=0;                   // new loop variable i
while (j=pow(4,i)) <= n do // equivalent loop condition which calculates j
    for l=1 to n-j do
        k=k+j;
    end for
    i=i+1;                 // equivalent to j=j*4
end while
```

The value of `i` increases as `0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...`, and the value of `j` as `1, 4, 16, 64, 256 ...` (i.e. powers of 4).

---

**Step 2**

What is the maximum value of `i`, i.e. how many times does the outer loop run? Inverting the equivalent loop condition:

```
     pow(4,i) <= n             // loop condition inequality
-->  i <= log4(n)              // take logarithm base-4 of both sides
-->  max(i) = floor(log4(n))   // round down
```

Now that the maximum value of `i` is known, it's time to re-write the code again:

```
i=0,k=0;                   
m=floor(log4(n))           // maximum value of i
while i<=m do              // equivalent loop condition in terms of i only
    j=pow(4,i)             // value of j for each i
    for l=1 to n-j do
        k=k+j;
    end for
    i=i+1;
end while
```

---

**Step 3**

You have correctly deduced that the inner loop runs for `n - j` times for every outer loop. This can be summed over all values of `j` to give the total time complexity:

```
       j≤n
T(n) =  ∑  (n - j)
        j

       i≤m
     =  ∑  (n - pow(4,i))      // using the results of steps 1) and 2)
       i=0

                 i≤m
     = (m+1)*n -  ∑  pow(4,i)   // separate the sum into two parts
                 i=0
       \_____/   \_________/
          A           B
```

The term `A` is obviously `O(n log n)`, because `m=floor(log4(n))`. What about `B`?

---

**Step 4**

`B` is a *geometric series*, for which there is a standard formula (source – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics))):

[image: [1]]

Substituting the relevant numbers `"a" = 1, "n" = m+1, "r" = 4`:

```
B = (pow(4,m+1) - 1) / (4 - 1)

  = 3 * pow(4, floor(log4(n))+1) - 3
```

If a number is rounded down (`floor`), the result is always *greater than the original value minus 1*. Therefore `m` can be asymptotically written as:

```
     m = log4(n) + O(1)

-->  B = 3 * pow(4, log4(n) + O(1)) - 3

       = 3 * pow(4, O(1)) * n - 3
         ----------------
           this is O(1)

       = O(n)
```

---

**Step 5**

`A = O(n log n), B = O(n)`, so asymptotically `A` overshadows `B`.

> The total time complexity is `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to calculate how many times each line will execute.

j=1,k=0;  // 1
while j<=n do  //n+1
    for l=1 to n-j do // ∑n
        k=k+j; //∑n-1
    end for 
    j=j*4; //n
end while

total complexity [add execution time of all lines] 
= 1+(n+1)+ ∑ n + ∑ (n-1) + n 
= 2n+2+ n^2/2 + n/2 + (n-1)^2/2 + (n-1)/2

take max term of above and skip constant factors then you will left with n^2
total runtime complexity will be o(n^2)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the is solution is O(nlogn)

Comment: My bad, I missed j=j*4; will edit solution soon